# Create SPFieldUserValue with full name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to create SPFieldUserValue using firstname lastmane combination?
I have first name and last name of user and wanted to find email address for that user.

-Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios where a last name and a first name are not unique. Think about it, what would happen if two people were named say Adam Smith?

Therefore there is no such constructor, and should not be such a constructor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.spfielduservalue(v=office.14).aspx